# Delete Duplicate Records 1 Day Apart

Tags: mysql

How could I remove a duplicate record based on a narrow time frame parameter? Each record has a unique date(data dump date). There is a common serial number and status number between duplicates - I only want to yank one duplicate from a day prior or later - and to be clear: In the future, I might capture another version of the same record containing the same serial / status number combination that I would *want to keep* - (other aspects of the record will have changed). My archive table makes sure there are no duplicate records based on the unique data date and serial number... but I can't figure out how to deal with the same record showing up the very next day and not having the option to simply group by status number as that number can show up many times over the course of a year, and I need to keep them.

This is my theoretical attempt, which would be run daily:

```
DELETE `t`
FROM `archive_table` as `t` JOIN
(SELECT `data-dump-date`, COUNT(`serial-number`)as `count` FROM 
`archive_table` 
WHERE

`data-dump-date` >= `todays-date` -1

GROUP BY `serial-number`,`status-number` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as `g` 
ON `t`.`data-dump-date` = `g`.`data-dump-date`
AND `t`.`serial-number` = `g`.`serial-number`
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but one thing you could do is prevent the duplicates from being inserted by checking for your criteria when you insert them...

Comment: That's a good point, I haven't looked into how I might write a query like yet.

Answer (score 1):

You do have the option to group by status number - just have a `CONCAT()` first so you can discriminate on the data also in that group.

`SELECT data-dump-date, serial-number, count(*) FROM archive_table GROUP BY CONCAT(data-dump-date, serial-number)`

Slightly more expensive query and the two other preferable options would be to not write in the first place, or to have actual unique serials numbers.  You might instead choose to do the `CONCAT()` on the write as that's only ever going to be two fields and affect one row as opposed to on the read as per my query which will affect the whole table.

No real reason why you couldn't write both the individual fields and also the `CONTAT()` result, except that you introduce the potential to have anomalies between the fields because you've copied the data and written it twice.  ie. if you `UPDATE` that row then you'd need to `UPDATE` both copies of your data in that row.